# postgres query with calculate before agregate

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

this is my structure table.

1. first table have information who person will be evaluate

Table master_object

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | mark |
| 2 | suzen |

2. seconds table is list of  indicators available of the person and value of answer

Table record_indikator

| obejct_id | is_active | val | indicator_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 6 | 1 | 1 | 3 |

i will be calculate result with join table  that result is simple

```
who much person aswer  all indicator with status active / how much person
```

how to calculate person aswered all active indicators

**example** for object_id =1
they have 1 answered then 2 indikators active
meaning is object 1 not answer all indikator. so that value for object 1 is zero.

**------------------------------------------------------**

**example** for object_id =2
they have 2 answered then 2 indikators active

meaning is object 2 answer all indikator and value is 1 for object 2.

so after this will be aggregate all value (0 (object 1) + 1 (object 2) )/2 Person = 0.5

**Question is how to build query efficient to get this result?**

and mybe have any sugestion arstiketurs or engine to support this more be fast.
note this records object is **more then 300 milions** at Years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to know what percentage of people answered all of the indicators. This can be accomplished with some conditional aggregations :

First we need to identify total active answers per person :

```
select r.object_id, sum(case when is_active=1 then 1 else 0 end) as total_actives, count(*) as total_records
from master_object m
inner join records_indikator r on r.object_id = m.id
group by r.object_id
```

Then check to see whether the totals are equivalent and do some math

```
select sum(case when total_actives = total_records then 1 else 0 end)::float/ count(*) as percentage
from (
  select r.object_id, sum(case when is_active=1 then 1 else 0 end) as total_actives, count(*) as total_records
  from master_object m
  inner join records_indikator r on r.object_id = m.id
  group by r.object_id
) as s
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/qzNb_0je)

Comment: thanks bro. any sugestion tech to improve speed query

Comment: I'm glad to hear:). Your tables will require some indexes. Upgrade to Postgresql's most recent version as well; it is undoubtedly more optimized